# OAuth2 для django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, oauth2

Подскажите какие нибудь хорошие библиотеки для подключения oauth2 в drf. Я нашёл только `django-rest-framework-social-oauth2`, может кто нибудь знает варианты получше? Или какие нибудь гайды, как в drf подключить oauth2

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй это - https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rest-framework/getting_started.html
На нескольких ресурсах рекомендуют.